# HTML Mouseover image over image rolls out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried so many combinations and this one is the nearest I could get to what I need.

What I need is an image (img1), with another (smaller) image (img2) over it, and when I rollover img1 I want it to fade in (and fade out on roll out), leaving img2 untouched.
The problem I'm getting is that when I rollover img2, that is over img1, Jquery think's I'm rolling out img1 and fades it out!

This is what I have so far:

```
.photo_link {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 133px;
    height: 410px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
#home_1 {
    background-image: 'photo_home_1.jpg');
}
.new {
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

<a class="photo_link">
    <span class="photo" id="home_1"></span>
    <img class="new src="new.png" />
</a>

$(function(){
    $('.photo')
        .mouseover(function(){
            $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
        })
});
```

Is there any way of avoiding this?

Comment: My assumption is that when you edited your source to post this question, you removed the `"` after `class="new"`. But you can see how Markdown is mis-highlighting your code. If that's not in your source, ignore this note.

Comment: this source is an example.. thank you anyway

Comment: See my answer below, including jsFiddle demo. If I understood you correctly, this will demonstrate what functionality you were describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the mouse events to the `.photo_link` element, and use [`$.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`$.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), which are not triggered when the mouse is no longer "over" an element when mousing "out" and over an element within it:

```
$(function(){
    $('.photo_link')
        .mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);
        })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
        })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CMyAZ/

If you `float; left`, you don't need `display: block` (which is implied). I cleaned up your CSS some. Also, I imagine you want to hide (`opacity: 0.2`) the element on page load (see [Quirksmode for cross-browser `opacity`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)):

```
.photo_link {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
#home_1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background: url('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG');
}
.new {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    border: 0;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: Please upvote. `:)` Also, I think this makes more sense as the answer, as the one currently marked doesn't actually solve the problem in reality. This is marked with the outlined checkmark (one answer may be accepted per question).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS animation also,

```
.photo_link>span{ 
display: block; 
transition: all 2s;
-moz-transition: all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: all 2s; /* Opera */
}

.photo_link:hover>span{ 
display: none;
}
```

Or with JS, simply apply fadeToggle i.e.:

```
$('.photo_link')
        .mouseover(function(){
            $(this).find("span").fadeToggle("fast");
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find("span").fadeToggle("fast");
        })
```

Also in your code i've found some bugs, -> class="new**"** src=" < " > is missing.

Comment: Great! Didn't know find(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, simple solution...

http://jsfiddle.net/YWzDH/3/

HTML:

```
<img class="img2" src="img2.jpg" />
<img class="img1" src="img1.jpg" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').live({
            mouseenter: function() {
              $('.img2').fadeTo("fast", 1);
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
              $('.img2').fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
            }
        }, '.img1, .img2');

});
```

CSS:

```
.img1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.img2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle links to code that's not in your answer, and `$.live()` is deprecated (use `$.on()` or `$.delegate()`), and there isn't any indication any of these are even needed.

Comment: This doesn't fix "the problem" (The problem I'm getting is that when I rollover img2, that is over img1, Jquery think's I'm rolling out img1 and fades it out!)